# Link shape coordinates browser in safari&IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

I used DW to link the picture. But SAFARI vs IE browsers, the line of the cut out areas.

How do I remove the line around? Do you any suggestion?

Please check in IE and SAFARI: http://demo.tasarim59.com/sari-nokta-hastaligi

Shape link example

```
<area shape="rect" coords="762,22,898,50" href="http://novartis.com.tr" target="_blank" />
```

Comment: Try with CSS: `AREA {outline: none;}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<img class="map" src="..." usemap="..." hidefocus="true" />
```

CSS

```
img.map{
    outline: none;
}
```

**This solution work perfect.**